# Doing two equal statements in one statement

Tags: php, if-statement, equals

How can i get this to work properly:

```
if ((empty($page_name))
 && ($currentid == '$storedid')) { // PHP If Statement with multiple Checks
  require_once("1.php");
} else { // PHP Else
  require_once("2.php");
}
```

Right now regardless its showing me 2.php....

$page_name is a value for a db table.  $currentid is session_id and $storedid is the stored id in the db for the $page_name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the single quotes in `($currentid == '$storedid')`

to

```
($currentid == $storedid)
```

Your solution compares $currentid with a static string. Because of the single quotes $storeid is interpreted as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Where you are using `'$storedid'`, it should be double quoted or not quoted at all. PHP is interpreting this as the literal string $storedid instead of parsing it as a variable.

Comment: Or better yet, he could just use it as a variable `$storedid`

Comment: @Cthos: Yep I spaced out on that one!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes surrounding `$storeId`, or put it in double quotes.